# error Missing helper file helpers/tags_helper.rb when install plugin redmineup_tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redmine

I've got received this error when try to install Redmine plugins redmineup_tags

My step to install this plugin:

- Unarchive plugin to folder redmine/plugins
- Go to `Redmine root` folder
- run `bundle install`
- run `bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmineup_tags RAILS_ENV=production`

The error appeared:

```
rake aborted!
AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError: Missing helper file helpers/tags_helper.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:151:in `rescue in block in modules_for_helpers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:148:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `map!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `modules_for_helpers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:94:in `modules_for_helpers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:108:in `helper'
.....
```

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it.
Wrong folder name.